# Different behavior between multiple nested lookups inside .filter and .exclude

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

What's the difference between having multiple nested lookups inside `queryset.filter` and `queryset.exclude`?

For example car ratings. User can create ratings of multiple types for any car.

```
class Car(Model):
    ...

class Rating(Model):
    type = ForeignKey('RatingType') # names like engine, design, handling
    user = ... # user
```

Let's try to get a list of cars without rating by user "a" and type "design".

**Approach 1**

```
car_ids = Car.objects.filter(
        rating__user="A",  rating__type__name="design"
    ).values_list('id',flat=True)

Car.objects.exclude(id__in=car_ids)
```

**Approach 2**

```
Car.objects.exclude(
        rating__user="A", rating__type__name="design"
    )
```

The **Approach 1** works well to me whereas the **Approach 2** looks to be excluding more cars. My suspicion is that nested lookup inside `exclude` does not behave like AND (for the rating), rather it behaves like OR.

Is that true? If not, why these two approaches results in different querysets?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `filter`, "*multiple parameters are joined via `AND` in the underlying SQL statement*". Your first approach results not in one but in two SQL queries roughly equivalent to:

```
SELECT ... WHERE rating.user='A' AND rating.type.name='design';
```

```
SELECT ... WHERE car.id NOT IN (id1, id2, id3 ...);
```

Here's the part of the documentation that answers your question very precisely regarding `exclude`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#exclude

The evaluated SQL query would look like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE NOT (rating.user='A' AND rating.type.name='design')
```

Nested lookups inside `filter` and `exclude` behave similarly and use `AND` conditions.  At the end of the day, most of the time, your 2 approaches are indeed equivalent... Except that the `Car` table might have been updated between the 1st and the 2d query of your approach 1.

Are you sure it's not the case? To be sure, try maybe to wrap the 2 lines of approach 1 in a [transaction.atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) block? In any case, your second approach is probably the best (the less queries, the better).

If you have any doubt, you can also have a look at the evaluated queries (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet)).

Comment: Thanks but they are different. I'm sure, it's tested multiple times. Looking on SQL it looks like it does WHERE NOT for this: Takes all the cars with rating design. Then in a second condition it takes all the cars from the first one and checks whether they have ANY rating by a given user. So if Car A has rating design by a different user, but also has a different rating by a given user, it is excluded.

Comment: Ok it took me some time to notice that `rating` isn't a Model attribute but a reverse look up. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships): "*The behavior of filter() for queries that span multi-value relationships, as described above, is not implemented equivalently for exclude(). Instead, the conditions in a single exclude() call will not necessarily refer to the same item.*".

Comment: So the only possible approach and what you're looking for is `Car.objects.exclude(rating__in=Rating.objects.filter(rating__user="A", rating__type__name="design"))` (slightly cleaner than your 1st approach even if it still corresponds to 2 queries).

Comment: Thanks! In fact, it's just one query so I'll use this.